# clicking a button remotely through python

Tags: python, http, buttonclick

i have tried clicking a button through `telit` modem,these were the commands i sent through the modem as http request,if the button is clicked the text in the `Textbox` will be deposited in the database.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1

Host: www.apcogsys.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 253
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www.apcogsys.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.apcogsys.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE0MDM4MzYxMjNkZMHxueuplKms5LprRiXrYhjNw1RQHyrxnbqdvUd7WuME&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAOXYiZ8Tx8yD9ysXMQzXW6cESCFkFW%2FRuhzY1oLb%2FNUVM34O%2FGfAV4V4n0wgFZHr3cvuT1CKH816XKYM4BbXnMYv8RXVACd0FKbHPtTjQthHg%3D%3D&TextBox1=abcde&Button1=click
```

`Button1=click` means that the button has been clicked.i have copied this set of commands from http debugger.But this is not working and the text in the textbox is not being deposited in the database.
All that has to happen is what ever is there in `TextBox1=abcde` part of the `viewstate` has to be deposited in the database.